# How to make wordpress use only one post per page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

What I want is to show only one blog post at a time, both on the front page and "after that", too, i.e. I don't want a second view of my blog that shows more than one post.

So far, I've set "posts per page" to 1 in the dashboard. However, the navigation links before and after the post link to page 2, page 3, etc. Those only show one post already, however I'd prefer those links to point to the next/previous posts' permalinks instead.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '</span>' ); ?></div>
</div>
```

The first block of code you should find in your `loop.php` and the second one comes from `single.php`.